# getting an error type int is not a subtype of string

Tags: flutter, dart

I creating a demo for sqlite where I have created a model class category model and in sqlite I have created some default categories in its on create method and now want to show all categories on home screen using future builder but its execute error part of feature builder..and app starts with center text

```
type int is not a subtype of string
```

category model

```
class CategoryModel{
  String title;
  IconData icon;
  int entries;
  double totalamount;

  CategoryModel({required this.title,this.entries=0,required this.icon,this.totalamount=0.0});

  Map<String,dynamic> tomap()
  {
    return {
      'title':title,
      'entries':entries,
      'totalamount':totalamount.toString()
    };
  }


  factory CategoryModel.frommap(Map<String,dynamic> map)
  {
    return CategoryModel(
        title: map['title'],
        icon: icons[map['title']]!,
        entries: map['entries'],
        totalamount: double.parse(map['totalamount'])
    );
  }

}
```

this is the widget where I am using futurebuilder

```
Widget getbody()
  {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: SqfliteProvider.fetchcategory(),
      builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List<CategoryModel>?>snapshot){
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()+' Founded'),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  CategoryModel t = snapshot.data![index];

                  print(t.title.toString());
                  print(' ');
                  print(t.entries.toString());
                  print(' ');
                  print(t.totalamount.toString());

                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        child:   Icon(icons[t.title]),

                      ),
                      title: Text(t.title.toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                      subtitle:Text(
                        "Entries :"+t.entries.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                      ) ,

                    ),
                  );
                });
          } else {
            return Text('Something wrong');
          }
        } else {
          return Text('Last if');
        }

      },
    );

  }
```

this is my database helper class

```
class SqfliteProvider {
  static Future<Database> _getdb() async {
    return openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'expensedb1.db'),
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (db,version) {
        db.execute("CREATE TABLE categorytb(title TEXT NOT NULL,entries INTEGER NOT NULL,totalamount STRING NOT NULL)");


      //add some default categories
      print('I am ready to call');
          for(int x=0;x<icons.length;x++)
           {
             db.insert('categorytb', {
               'title':icons.keys.toList()[x],
               'entries':0,
               'totalamount':(0.0).toString()
             });
           }

        });
  }

  static Future<List<CategoryModel>?> fetchcategory() async{
    final db=await _getdb();

    List<CategoryModel> templist=[];
    List<Map<String,dynamic>> maplist=await db.query('categorytb');

    print(maplist.toString());


    if(maplist.isEmpty)
      return null;

    templist=maplist.map((e) => CategoryModel.frommap(e)).toList();
    return templist;

  }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert toString.

```dart
factory CategoryModel.frommap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  IconData getIconData(data) {
    try {
      return IconData(data);
    } catch (e) {
      return IconData(Icons.abc.codePoint);
    }
  }

  return CategoryModel(
    title: map['title'].toString(),
    icon: getIconData(map['title']), // pass different data if needed
    entries: int.tryParse(map['entries'].toString()) ?? 0,
    totalamount: double.tryParse(map['totalamount']) ?? 0,
  );
}
```

Comment: already tried that but getting the same error

Comment: Oh, I've reversed the error, can you  printing data

Comment: seems `totalamount` giving you int then

Comment: if I place totalamout=0.0 it works....but so looks like error coming from this statement...

Comment: Done....I just changed totalamount=double.parse(map['total amount'].toString()